# issue when disable checkbox node

Tags: javascript, checkbox, jstree

i want to make a jstree with checkbox plugin. when the jstree load, i want some nodes are checked and their state can not be changed any more. i find a way to disable the checkbox node, but when i change its' parent node state, the child node may still change itself's state.

here is the way i found to disable the checkbox node:

```
"types" : {
     "types": {
     "disabled" : { 
           "check_node" : false, 
           "uncheck_node" : false 
         } 
     }
}

$.jstree._reference('#tree').set_type("disabled", "#node5");
```

Comment: does anybody solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can disable selecting child nodes automatically when the parent is selected by configuring the checkbox plugin this way

```
$("#tree").jstree({
    "checkbox" : {
      "three_state" : false
    },
    "plugins" : [ "checkbox" ]
  });
```